# How to replay Git repository history into subdirectory?

Tags: git

Let's say I've got two repositories `aye` and `bee` and I want to get rid of `bee`, in such a way that the linear history of `bee/master` is "replayed" in a new subdirectory (several levels deep) of `aye`. **I just want the files and the commit messages, I don't care about commit IDs.** I *do* want a sensible history, so [`git subtree add --prefix=subdirectory`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14992078/96588) and [`git read-tree --prefix=subdirectory/`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1426163/96588) are not what I'm looking for.

Both repositories are private, so there's no risk of rewriting history for someone else. However, `bee` *does* have a submodule `cee`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, [rewrite `bee`'s history to move all files into the subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4042965/96588):

```
cd /path/to/bee
git filter-branch --force --prune-empty --tree-filter '
dir="my fancy/target directory"
if [ ! -e "$dir" ]
then
    mkdir --parents "${dir}"
    git ls-tree --name-only "$GIT_COMMIT" | xargs -I files mv files "$dir"
fi'
```

`git log --stat` should show every file appearing under `my fancy/target directory`. Now you can [merge the history into `aye` with ease](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10548919/96588):

```
cd /path/to/aye
git remote add -f bee /path/to/bee
git checkout -b bee-master bee/master
git rebase master
git checkout master
git rebase bee-master
```

Recreate the submodule in `aye`:

```
git submodule add git://my-submodule 'my fancy/target directory/my-submodule'
```

Finally you can clean up `aye`:

```
git rm 'my fancy/target directory/.gitmodules'
git branch --delete --force bee-master
git remote remove bee
```

You may also have to fix any absolute paths in your repository (for example in `.gitignore`)

Comment: Condition check caused an error: `/usr/lib/git-core/git-filter-branch: 3: eval: [[: not found`. Had to remove lines with `if`, `then` and `fi` and job was done, thanks! Ubuntu 18.04; git 2.22.0; bash 4.4.20

Comment: You're not using Bash then. I've changed it to be more POSIX compatible.

Answer (score 4):

Much faster version (hat tip to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13590229)):

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git ls-files -s | sed "s-\t\"*-&newsubdir/-" | GIT_INDEX_FILE=$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new git update-index --index-info && mv "$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new" "$GIT_INDEX_FILE"'
```

Replace `newsubdir` with any directory or nested directory you like. On macOS, you may have to use `gsed` instead of `sed` (install with `brew install gnu-sed`).